# WSO2-IS 5.10.0 - Service Provider - OAuthAdminServiceIdentityOAuthAdminException

Tags: oauth, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to configure an OAuth/OpenId connect on Service Providers in WSO2 Identity Server and I'm facing an error:

```
Error occurred while adding the application : OAuthAdminServiceIdentityOAuthAdminException
```

wso2-is.log:

```
[2021-04-23 14:20:35,113] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} 
- 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2021-04-23 14:20:35,112+0000]
[2021-04-23 14:24:16,379] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminService} 
- org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.IdentityOAuthAdminException: Error when adding the application.
 An application with the same name already exists.
```

PS: I don't know if it is correlated but I changed the internal database from h2 to mysql. On IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS table is showing CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET.

What am I missing to do to work in carbon console since is showing **Configure** yet bellow "**OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration**"?

Comment: Can you check if there is an entry in IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS table with application name you are trying to create for APP_NAME column?

Comment: Yes, there is. But I'm trying to configure OAuth/OpenId.

Comment: OAuth/OpenId configurations are stored in IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS table. So you have to remove the current entry and retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the Service Provider from WSO2-IS console and also from IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS table, and then I've recreated everything again.

Now it is showing on WSO-IS console.

[image]